Why my file is getting stored in external storage on API 28 even after permission denied?
I am building one android app in which I am trying to save file in External storage. I am running that app on API 28 (Before introduction of scoped storage).
When the app launches, I am denying the storage permission but still, able to create and write file in external storage. When I searched how is this happening, I got some answers like emulators might behave differently that real devices. So, I tried running app on API 28 real device from firebase test lab. But still, same thing is happening. I wonder why so? Following is my code to create file and write in it on external storage.
val externalFile = File(getExternalFilesDir(null), externalFileName)
externalFile.writeText(binding.etExtFileContents.text.toString())
Toast.makeText(this, "Saved contents in file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Here are the permission in manifest:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="32" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

I am not checking for permission before writing to the file because I wanted it to fail. I want to understand the behavior.

You've never needed the storage permission to write to getExternalFilesDir(null). What made you think you needed permissions to write to that folder?

@ianhanniballake isn't this writing to external storage? so, where we needed a permission to write file, I am trying to clear the concept, can you please tell?

@AshishJoshi: This is covered in the documentation. I also cover it in this chapter of this free book.
